# ¿Como reescribir el enlazado interno en entorno de preproduccion?

Tags: wordpress, seo, migration

Estoy preparando una migración en la que todo el enlazado interno, por error de importación, apunta hacia el entorno de preproduccion -> https://preproduccion.com/enlace-1 Lo correcto seria -> https://produccion.com/enlace-1

Es decir, la mayoría de enlaces internos apuntan hacia el dominio que no debería de tal modo que cuando haga la migracion y las DNS apunten hacia mi servidor, estos enlaces responderan 403 forbidden.

¿Como puedo hacer para reescribir todos estos enlaces y que apunten al dominio de producción, de tal modo que cuando haga la migración dirijan correctamente? Reemplazarlo a mano es totalmente inviable.

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias razones por las cuales puede hacerse un redireccionamiento, aquí una guía básica para revisar tus enlaces.

**1. Revisa la tabla wp_options**

Cuando se hace una migración manual e incluso con plugins, pasa que la tabla wp_options, específicamente en las celdas site_url y home a veces (en especial si es una migración manual) siguen las urls antiguas, modifica las celdas con las urls de tu sitio actual, por ejemplo, https://sitioenproduccion.com cámbialo a https://copiadesitioenproduccion.com sin usar un / al final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**htaccess**

Si la url es correcta y aun así sigue redireccionando, trata de reiniciar el htaccess por el htaccess por defecto, aquí un ejemplo https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/htaccess-por-defecto-predeterminado-wordpress/

**Plugins de redireccionamiento**

Si aun con eso sigue redireccionando al sitio en producción, entonces revisa si tienes plugins de redireccionamiento, si no puedes acceder a wp-admin intenta cambiar el nombre de la carpeta plugins por plugins-old o parecido, si puedes ingresar después de eso entonces desactiva el plugin y recarga los enlaces permanentes, luego verifica si sigue redireccionando.

**Enlaces permanentes**

También pasa a veces que los enlaces permanentes no se actualizan, si puedes ingresar a wp-admin y lo que te redirecciona son paginas internas o el home, entonces intenta actualizar los enlaces permanentes.

**Recargar cache**

Si luego de eso sigue redireccionando, prueba a recargar el cache o entrando en modo incognito, a veces pasa que se soluciono el problema pero el cache sigue guardando las urls antiguas.

**Otros métodos**

Si después de eso sigue pasando entonces prueba a verificar si hay alguna redirección en el código fuente del tema, en especial en el archivo functions.php o bien, prueba a ingresar al archivo wp-config.php y revisar si hay alguna redirección o se esta **reescribiendo** el site url y home url, por ultimo, también revisa otras tablas en la base de datos, si tienes muchos plugins es posible que aunque no sea de redirección siga guardando las urls antiguas, en especial plugins de cache, intenta hacer una búsqueda en la db y verificar que no haya ningún enlace al sitio anterior.

Espero esta mini guía te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Hola, creo que no has entendido bien el problema o yo no me he explicado bien. El problema es que todos los enlaces internos en preproduccion apuntan hacia un host de preproduccion (http://preproduccion.com/url-de-ejemplo) y cuando realice la migración a producción y el sitio esté live, estos enlaces deberían apuntar al host correcto (http://produccion.com/url-de-ejejmplo). Mi problema es ¿Como hago para que los enlaces internos se reescriban al host correcto sin tener que hacerlo a mano?